# What is the intuition behind simhash?

Tags: hash-function

Why does simhash work?  I understand how to implement the hash algorithm, mechanically, from the many articles such as http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/.  But is there a simple intuitive explanation for why this particular procedure is so effective at capturing similarity?

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify what problem you are asking about?  The assumption in the question is that simhash (whatever it is) works, but works _for what_?  The question talks about “capturing similarity,” but similarity _of what_?

Comment: Isn't the whole premise of simhash that (from the link) "similar items are hashed to similar hash values (by similar we mean the bitwise hamming distance between hash values)"? I believe "items" is generally documents, strings, etc.

Comment: Well, I do not know what simhash is.  I am just trying to help you state your question in such a way that theoretical computer science can be useful.  In the current form, it is unclear to me why you are asking this question on a website about theoretical computer science.